How can I change limit in ForEach?
I'm using workflow to execute a part of my script.
I'm trying to execute this command :
ForEach -Parallel ($Data in $DataList) { MyJob }
The problem is the parallel limit. ForEach limit the number of script blocks that run in parallel to 5.
How can I run more than 5 script blocks ?
I tried to use "ThrottleLimit" parameter but it does not work....
Thank you for your help

Easy, stop using workflows :)

what evne is Workflows in this context?

Stop using Workflow, if you have another idea, tell me. It is the only way I know
The context : I'm working on multiple servers. The first script worked on servers one by one. It took long time. So I create workflow to parallelize the process and gain about 8h. If I can change parallel limit, I can gain 3h more

Question: can you use Powershell 7.x? If not, this answer might help.

@olivier The simplest answer is "just use Invoke-Command" to dispatch the same workload on multiple servers concurrently. If you want more specific advice: share your code

The ThrottleLimit parameter ?

@CrookedJ that's for ForEach-Object, OP is asking about ForEach from the Workflows module, which I think it was an older workaround for parallelizing stuff on 5.1?

Yes I'm working on PowerShell 5.1
Maybe my approch is not correct and I should use something else. I made the there was 2 years ago, so it may be updated :)

My mistake. Yeah, don't use workflows :~D

Ok, thank you. I will think to change it. :D
